# Why webRTC only showing remote video stream when the two clients are in the same network?

Tags: video, socket.io, webrtc

I am trying to run a sample webRTC program.

I am trying to show client and peer video in a page .

If the two clients (my pc and my phone) are in the same network works fine.

If I disconnect phone from Wifi, all works fine (no errors in console) but the remote video not appears.

parts of Code:

```
<video id="webrtc-remotevid" autoplay style="width: 70%;"></video>
<video id="webrtc-sourcevid" autoplay muted style="width: 30%;"></video>

<script>
    // create socket
    var socket = io.connect('streaming.efectotest.com:3478/');

    var sourcevid = document.getElementById('webrtc-sourcevid');
    var remotevid = document.getElementById('webrtc-remotevid');
    var localStream = null;
    var peerConn = null;
    var started = false;
    var channelReady = false;
    var mediaConstraints = {'mandatory': {
                          'OfferToReceiveAudio':true, 
                          'OfferToReceiveVideo':true }};

    // starts local video
    function startVideo() {
        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
        window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL; 

        navigator.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: true}, successCallback, errorCallback);
        function successCallback(stream){
            localStream = stream;
            if (sourcevid.mozSrcObject){
                sourcevid.mozSrcObject = stream;
                sourcevid.play();
            } 
            else {
                try {
                    sourcevid.srcObject = stream; 
                    sourcevid.play();
                } 
                catch(e){
                    console.log("Error setting video src: ", e);
                }
            }
        }

        function errorCallback(error) {
            console.error('An error occurred: [CODE ' + error.code + ']');
            return;
        }
    }

    // stop local video
    function stopVideo() {
        if (sourcevid.mozSrcObject){
            sourcevid.mozSrcObject.stop();
            sourcevid.src = null;
        }
        else {
            sourcevid.src = "";
            localStream.stop();
        }
    }

    // send SDP via socket connection
    function setLocalAndSendMessage(sessionDescription) {
        peerConn.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
        console.log("SEND -- Sending: SDP");
        console.log(sessionDescription);
        socket.json.send(sessionDescription);
    }

    function createOfferFailed() {
        console.log("Fallo al CONECTAR");
    }

    // start the connection upon user request
    function connect() {
        if (!started && localStream && channelReady) {
            createPeerConnection();
            started = true;
            peerConn.createOffer(setLocalAndSendMessage, createOfferFailed, mediaConstraints);
            console.log('conexión efectuada');
        }
        else {
            alert("La transmisión local aún no se está ejecutando. Vuelve a intentarlo.");
        }
    }

    // stop the connection upon user request
    function hangUp() {
        console.log("Hang up.");    
        socket.json.send({type: "bye"});
        stop();
    }

    function stop() {
        peerConn.close();
        peerConn = null;
        started = false;    
    }

    // socket: channel connected
    socket.on('connect', onChannelOpened)
          .on('message', onMessage);

    function onChannelOpened(evt) {
        console.log('Canal abierto.');
        channelReady = true;
    }

    function createAnswerFailed() {
        console.log("FALLO AL CREAR Answer");
    }

    // socket: accept connection request
    function onMessage(evt) {
        if (evt.type === 'offer'){
            console.log("Received offer...")
            if (!started) {
                createPeerConnection();
                started = true;
            }
            console.log('Creating remote session description...' );
            peerConn.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(evt));
            console.log('Sending answer...');
            peerConn.createAnswer(setLocalAndSendMessage, createAnswerFailed, mediaConstraints);
        } 
        else if (evt.type === 'answer' && started) {
            console.log('Received answer...');
            console.log('Setting remote session description...' );
            peerConn.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(evt));
        } 
        else if (evt.type === 'candidate' && started){
            console.log('Received ICE candidate...');
            var candidate = new RTCIceCandidate({sdpMLineIndex:evt.sdpMLineIndex, sdpMid:evt.sdpMid, candidate:evt.candidate});

            console.log(candidate);
            peerConn.addIceCandidate(candidate);

        } 
        else if (evt.type === 'bye' && started) {
            console.log("Received bye");
            stop();
        }
    }

    function createPeerConnection() {
        console.log("Creating peer connection");
        RTCPeerConnection = webkitRTCPeerConnection || mozRTCPeerConnection;

        var pc_config = {"iceServers":[]};

        try {
            peerConn = new RTCPeerConnection(pc_config);
            started = true;
            console.log("CREADO peerConn");

            console.log(peerConn.getConfiguration());
        } 
        catch (e) {
            console.log("FALLO AL CREAR  PeerConnection, ERROR: " + e.message);
        }

        // send any ice candidates to the other peer CANDIDATOS 
        peerConn.onicecandidate = function (evt) {
            if (event.candidate) {
                console.log('Sending ICE candidate...');
                console.log(evt.candidate);
                socket.json.send({type: "candidate",
                sdpMLineIndex: evt.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
                sdpMid: evt.candidate.sdpMid,
                candidate: evt.candidate.candidate});
            } 
            else {
                console.log("End of candidates.");
            }
        };

        console.log('Adding local stream...');
        peerConn.addStream(localStream);

        peerConn.addEventListener("addstream", onRemoteStreamAdded, false);
        peerConn.addEventListener("removestream", onRemoteStreamRemoved, false)
    }

        // when remote adds a stream, hand it on to the local video element
    function onRemoteStreamAdded(event) {
        console.log("external video");
        setTimeout(function(){emmm(event.stream);},20000);
    }

    function emmm(stream){
        remotevid.srcObject = stream;
        remotevid.load();
        setTimeout(function(){ alert('playing'); remotevid.play();},5000);
    }

    // when remote removes a stream, remove it from the local video element
    function onRemoteStreamRemoved(event) {
        console.log("ELIMINADO REMOTO stream");
        remotevid.src = "";
    }

  </script>
```

JS socket server

```
const express = require('express');
const socketIO = require('socket.io');
const https = require('https');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express();

var port = process.env.port || 3478;
let server = https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('domain-key.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('domain-crt.crt')
}, app).listen(port, function(){
    console.log("https server listening en puerto " + port);
});

const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, '/public');

app.use(express.static(publicPath));

const publicPath_3 = path.join(__dirname, '/public/servidor.html');
app.get('/videochat',function(req, res){res.sendFile(publicPath_3);});

var io = socketIO(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Connection established.');

    socket.on('message', function(message) {
        console.log((new Date()) + ' Received Message, broadcasting: ' + message);
        socket.broadcast.emit('message', message);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log((new Date()) + " Peer disconnected.");
        socket.broadcast.emit('user disconnected');
    });
});
```

Any help?

Comment: Stop mangling candidates. See https://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#examples-and-call-flows

Comment: Have you been able to get any diagnostics via browser WebRTC tools.  For example in chrome using chrome://webrtc-internals or in Firefox about:webrtc page.  You may then be able to trace the flow and any issue with the Video transmission